# ¿Como copiar contenido de un zip a una directorio de android?

Tags: java, android, zip

***Hola a todos.***

*Formule esta pregunta con el fin de que pudiesen darme una mano y orientarme en mi camino.*

### Mi problema

*Quiero ser capas de poder descomprimir un zip en una carpeta o directorio de la sdcard, pero mi código no ha dado en el blanco. Su falla es que no descomprime o copia ninguno de los archivos en su interior el zip se encuentra en la carpeta de recurso Assets.*

### Mi código

```
    private boolean copyFile1(String filename1, String outPath1) {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
    final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4;
    InputStream in;
    OutputStream out;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(filename1);
        String newFileName = outPath1;

        ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(in);
        ZipEntry zEntry = null;
        while ((zEntry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {


            if (zEntry.isDirectory()) {

            } else {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(outPath1));
                BufferedOutputStream bufout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = zipStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    bufout.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                zipStream.closeEntry();
                bufout.close();
                fout.close();
            }
        }
        zipStream.close();
        Log.d("Unzip", "Unzipping complete. path :  " );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
    }
    return true;

}
```

***Si notan donde fallo o conocen otra forma. Por favor comunicármela. Gracias***

Comment: ¿No te muestra algún error? Si sí, edita tu pregunta y agrega los errores que te arroja.

Comment: No me muestra ningún error de sistema y el método se ejecuta solo que no se copia nada.

Comment: El archivo a descomprimir donde se encuentra, que parametros envias al método? Que sistema operativo usas? Es importante revisar el LogCat para tener más detalle de este problema @Abraham.P

Comment: Se encuentra en assets, lo que envió es el nombre del zip que esta en assets y la ruta donde quiero descomprimir. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienes definido el permiso y usas android 6+ además de agregar el permiso a tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Debes requerir permisos manualmente mediante:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 507;

    private void checkWritePermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // No action!.
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }
    }


    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    // Permiso negado.                                  
                }
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

---

Preguntaba acerca de las rutas que envias a tu método, los paths de los archivos deben estar definidos dentro del almacenamiento externo, por ejemplo:

```
String archivoZip = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/archivoszip/miarchivo.zip";
String directorioArchivosDecompresos  = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/archivosdescomprimidos/";
```

### Copiar contenido de un .zip a una directorio en android.

Para esto se tiene que descomprimir y agrego esta clase que sera de utilidad:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import android.util.Log;

public class Decompressfile {

    private String zipFile;
    private String decompresslocation;

    public Decompressfile(String zipFile, String location) {
        this.zipFile = zipFile;
        this.decompresslocation = location;

        _dirChecker("");
    }

    public void unzip() {
        try  {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
            ZipEntry ze = null;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

                if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                    _dirChecker(ze.getName());
                } else {
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(decompresslocation + ze.getName());
                    BufferedOutputStream bufout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        bufout.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }




                    bufout.close();

                    zin.closeEntry();
                    fout.close();
                }

            }
            zin.close();


            Log.d("Unzip", "Unzipping complete. path :  " + decompresslocation);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);

            Log.d("Unzip", "Unzipping failed");
        }

    }

    private void _dirChecker(String dir) {
        File f = new File(decompresslocation + dir);

        if(!f.isDirectory()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
    }

}
```

Para usarla sería de esta forma:

```
    String archivoZip = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/archivoszip/miarchivo.zip";
    String directorioArchivosDecompresos = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/archivosdescomprimidos/"; 

new Decompressfile(archivoZip, directorioArchivosDecompresos).unzip();
```

Comment: No están definidos en el almacenamiento externo si no en la /sdcard y la carpeta assets, y he podido copiar contenido a los ficheros que están en /sdcard, pero el problema se dio al querer descomprimir un zip en una carpeta. Pero si este código resolverá este problema perfecto, pero una duda este código pide permiso como el del manifest   y la duda mía es lo siguiente me permite la declaración en el  manifest poder copiar contenido a ficheros pero no permite poder descomprimir archivos en un directorio. Gracias por el aporte

Comment: ok en la SDCard, recuerda que la carpeta /assets es solo lectura, la carpeta en donde deseas descomprimir el archivo en donde se encuentra? @Abraham.P

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Agregué una clase que uso, solo necesitas tener previamente los permisos y asignar la ruta del archivo .zip y el directorio donde deseas se guarden los archivos que contiene el .zip, saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ @Abraham.P

Comment: Gracias por todo.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que sea un error de permisos.
Comprueba que tienes incluida la siguiente linea en tu AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Por otro lado, no sé cómo pasas el path a tu método, pero deberías hacerlo en un ruta cuya base fuera obtenida así:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Comment: Gracias pero ya intentado esto y no me funcionado.